# Does AssemblyCleanup have a time limit

Tags: tfs, mstest

Do methods marked with the AssemblyCleanup attribute have a maximum time limit?

We have a method that does a bunch of database deletes for the test data that has been added during the test run, and we don't see that this method is given time to complete fully.

(We are using Visual Studio 2008 Team System.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing documented means not defined.

Try running with a long `Thread.Sleep` and see what happens.